# How to install docker in Jenkins without root privileges?

Tags: for-loop, docker, jenkins, installation

I don`t have root privileges. Jenkins and tomcat installed via wget command on Ubuntu 16. How to install docker in Jenkins without root privileges?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/477551

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You will need root privileges to install Docker. You would typically install Docker using the apt packages for Ubuntu. The apt package system requires root to install packages.